# How to embed dynamic data into a JSON string

Tags: reactjs, json, input, dynamic, embed

I'm working on a React app that interacts with JW Playe API. The API wants me to send data in JSON format. The problem is that I need to embed dynamic input data into that JSON string. I don't know how to do that. Please help me out.

Here is the JSON object:

```
const data =
      '{ "upload": { "method": "fetch", "download_url": I NEED TO PUT DATA COMING FROM REACT STATE (Input) HERE }, "metadata": {"title": "My Fetch Video", "author": "Dzenis H."} }';
```

Comment: can you explain a little more about your problem? that part "dynamic input data" is not really clear to me... but for editing the JSON, you can use `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringfy()` to get values from a JSON and convert object to a valid JSON

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh I need to put data coming from the HTML input element inside of a JSON string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
  const data = '{ "upload": { "method": "fetch", "download_url": "I NEED TO PUT DATA COMING FROM REACT STATE (Input) HERE" }, "metadata": {"title": "My Fetch Video", "author": "Dzenis H."} }';

  const updateJson = () => {
    let parseData = JSON.parse(data);
    parseData.upload.download_url = url;
    let converted = JSON.stringify(parseData);
    console.log(converted);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={url} onChange={e => setUrl(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={updateJson}>Update</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```